# Google Speech recognition doesn't consistently enter the speech into app text field

Tags: voice-recognition, text-input, swiftkey, huawei-p20

I cannot figure out the whole pattern but much of the time these days if I use Google Speech to recognise some text to put into a text field eg Facebook's or Messenger's, it successfully recognises the text (it shows me) but then when the popup displaying the text goes away, it leaves the text field unchanged, instead of entering the recognised text. It seems to happen mostly if I do some speech recognition, then edit or move the cursor, then some more speech recognition.

Is there any way to force the recognised text into that field or get it into "paste" so I can paste it in?

(Using a Huawei P20 Pro running Android 10 and Microsoft Swiftkey to "activate" Google Speech).